# How to configure SparkContext for a HA enabled Cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

When I am trying to run the spark application in YARN mode using the HDFS file system it works fine when I provide the below properties.

```
sparkConf.set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.hostname",resourcemanagerHostname);
sparkConf.set("spark.hadoop.yarn.resourcemanager.address",resourcemanagerAddress);
sparkConf.set("spark.yarn.stagingDir",stagingDirectory );
```

But the problems with this are:

1. Since my HDFS is NamdeNode HA enabled it won't work when I provide spark.yarn.stagingDir the commons URL of hdfs

E.g. `hdfs://hdcluster/user/tmp/` gives an error that says:

> has unknown host hdcluster

But it works fine when I give the URL as `hdfs://<ActiveNameNode>/user/tmp/`, but we don't know in advance which will be active so how do I resolve this?

And few things I have noticed are SparkContext takes the Hadoop configuration but SparkConfiguration class won't have any methods to accepts Hadoop configuration.

2. How do I provide the resource Manager address when Resource Manager are running in HA?

Comment: please edit your question properly. put code in a section `like this`. No need to write Thanks and name in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the configuration parameters that are already present in hadoop config files like [`yarn-site.xml`](http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/yarn-site.xml), [`hdfs-site.xml`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml)

Initialize the `Configuration` object using:

```
val conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration()
```

To check the current HDFS URI, use:

```
val currentFS = conf.get("fs.defaultFS");
```

You will get an output with the URI of your namenode, something like:

```
res0: String = hdfs://namenode1
```

To check the address of current resource manager in use, try:

```
val currentRMaddr = conf.get("yarn.resourcemanager.address")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the exact same issue. Here is the solution (finally):

You have to configure the internal Spark Context Hadoop Configuration for HDFS HA. When instantiating the Spark Context or Spark Session, it will find all configurations which have keys starting with `spark.hadoop.` and use them in instantiate the Hadoop Configuration.

So, In order to be able to use `hdfs://namespace/path/to/file` and not get an Invalid Host Exception is to add the following configuration options

```
spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS = "hdfs://my-namespace-name"
spark.hadoop.ha.zookeeper.quorum = "real.hdfs.host.1.com:2181,real.hdfs.host.2.com:2181"
spark.hadoop.dfs.nameservices = "my-namespace-name"
spark.hadoop.dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.my-namespace-name = org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider
spark.hadoop.dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled.my-namespace-name = true
spark.hadoop.dfs.ha.namenodes.my-namespace-name = "realhost1,realhost2"
spark.hadoop.dfs.namenode.rpc-address.my-namespace-name.realhost1 = "real.hdfs.host.1.com:8020"
spark.hadoop.dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address.my-namespace-name.realhost1 = "real.hdfs.host.1.com:8022"
spark.hadoop.dfs.namenode.http-address.my-namespace-name.realhost1 = "real.hdfs.host.1.com:50070"
spark.hadoop.dfs.namenode.https-address.my-namespace-name.realhost1 = "real.hdfs.host.1.com:50470"
spark.hadoop.dfs.namenode.rpc-address.my-namespace-name.realhost2 = "real.hdfs.host.2.com:8020"
spark.hadoop.dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address.my-namespace-name.realhost2 = "real.hdfs.host.2.com:8022"
spark.hadoop.dfs.namenode.http-address.my-namespace-name.realhost2 = "real.hdfs.host.2.com:50070"
spark.hadoop.dfs.namenode.https-address.my-namespace-name.realhost2 = "real.hdfs.host.2.com:50470"
spark.hadoop.dfs.replication = 3
spark.hadoop.dfs.blocksize = 134217728
spark.hadoop.dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname = false
spark.hadoop.dfs.datanode.hdfs-blocks-metadata.enabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking at `HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/path/to/hdfs-site.xml/and/core-site.xml` property in `spark-env.sh`. The mentioned envioronment variable should point to location where `hdfs-site.xml` and `core-site.xml` exists (Same those used in starting hadoop HA cluster). You should be able to then use `hdfs://namespace/path/to/file` without issues